# C# QUery if user exists - Passing Domain name from Combobox returns default domain

Tags: c#

I have a line of class with the following

```
namespace MYApp.ISec
{
  public class ActiveDirectory
    {
        public static string DomainValue { get; set; }
        public PrincipalContext mydom = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainValue);
        public bool DoesUserExist(string userName)
            {

                {
                using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(mydom, userName))
                {
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("User Found");
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No User");
                        return false;
                    }

                }

                }


            }
    



    }
}
```

and on my winform i have this

```
private void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == -1 || metroTextBox2.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Domain or Username has not been completed, Please try again!", "Validation Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveDirectory.DomainValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() ;
                ActiveDirectory.DoesUserExist(metroTextBox2.Text);
            }
        }
```

there are two domain names within this combobox lets just say Domain1 and domain2

No matter what i select on the combobox it always defaults to my connected domain which is domain1 even if i select domain2

Does anyone have any solutions please because i have been at this for 5 hours now and it seems like i am missing something to easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static bool DoesUserExist(string domain, string userName)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
    {
        var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);

        if (user != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
     }

     return false;
}
```

And you will need to add into usings:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
```

PrincipalContext will be of type domain and particular domain will be set from param. Search is done trough identity (user name) on domain specified in context. PrincipalContext is IDisposable so should be properly disposed.

Answer (score 0):

PrincipalContext dosen't change when change property

```cs
   ActiveDirectory.DomainValue = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() ;
```

Try to create your Principal at start of DoesUserExist method

```cs
public bool DoesUserExist(string userName)
{
    mydom = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainValue);

    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(mydom, userName))
    {
       if (user != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("User Found");
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           MessageBox.Show("No User");
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm that one worked thank you

However my idea was eventually i am going to be creating more methods and in an ideal world i would like to have the principalcontext at the top so i can just reuse it in every method/function i create if thats possible

Comment: or you can try to do this one. You can recreate principalContext every time you change the DomainValue property.
public static string _domainValue { get; set; }
        public static string DomainValue { 
            get
            {
                return _domainValue;
            }
            set {
                public PrincipalContext mydom = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, value);
                _domainValue = value;
            } 
        }